# How do I show custom field in Sensei LMS Certificates plugin PDF

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, fpdf

I am using **"Sensei LMS"** and **"Sensei LMS Certificates"** plugins.

Now , to enhance **"Sensei LMS Certificates"** plugin functionality , I have created a custom meta box and custom fields like this : https://prnt.sc/104s7oy

I am using this action hook `sensei_certificates_before_pdf_output` to show text in PDF

I have added the following code in my custom plugin :

```
<?php 

add_action( 'sensei_certificates_before_pdf_output',  'action__sensei_certificates_before_pdf_output' , 20, 2 );
function action__sensei_certificates_before_pdf_output( $pdf_certificate, $fpdf ) {

    global $woothemes_sensei_certificates;

    $show_border    = apply_filters( 'woothemes_sensei_certificates_show_border', 0 );
    $start_position = 200;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'certificate',
        'meta_key'   => 'certificate_hash',
        'meta_value' => $pdf_certificate->hash,
    );

    $query          = new WP_Query( $args );
    $certificate_id = 0;

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();
        $certificate_id = $query->posts[0]->ID;

    } 

    wp_reset_query();

    if ( 0 < intval( $certificate_id ) ) {

        $user_id      = get_post_meta( $certificate_id, 'learner_id', true );
        $student      = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $student_name = $student->display_name;
        $fname        = $student->first_name;
        $lname        = $student->last_name;

        if ( '' != $fname && '' != $lname ) {
            $student_name = $fname . ' ' . $lname;
        }

        $course_id       = get_post_meta( $certificate_id, 'course_id', true );
        $course_title    = get_post_field('post_title', $course_id);
        $course_end      = Sensei_Utils::sensei_check_for_activity(
            array(
                'post_id' => intval( $course_id ),
                'user_id' => intval( $user_id ),
                'type'    => 'sensei_course_status',
            ),
            true
        );
        $course_end_date = $course_end->comment_date;       

        $date = Woothemes_Sensei_Certificates_Utils::get_certificate_formatted_date( $course_end_date );

        if ( isset( $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields['certificate_custom_message']['text'] ) && '' != $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields['certificate_custom_message']['text'] ) {

            $certificate_custom_message = $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields['certificate_custom_message']['text'];
            $certificate_custom_message .= str_replace( array( '{{learner}}', '{{course_title}}', '{{completion_date}}', '{{course_place}}' ), array( $student_name, $course_title, $date, get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ), $certificate_custom_message );

        } 

        $output_fields = array(
            
            'certificate_custom_message' => 'textarea_field',
            
        );

        foreach ( $output_fields as $meta_key => $function_name ) {
    
            if ( isset( $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields[ $meta_key ]['position']['x1'] ) ) {

                $font_settings = $woothemes_sensei_certificates->get_certificate_font_settings( $meta_key );
                
                call_user_func_array( array( $pdf_certificate, $function_name ), array( $fpdf, $meta_key, $show_border, array( $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields[ $meta_key ]['position']['x1'], $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields[ $meta_key ]['position']['y1'], $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields[ $meta_key ]['position']['width'], $woothemes_sensei_certificates->certificate_template_fields[ $meta_key ]['position']['height'] ), $font_settings ) );
            } 
        }

    } else {

        wp_die( esc_html__( 'The certificate you are searching for does not exist.', '' ), esc_html__( 'Certificate Error', '' ) );

    } 

}
```

but this is how text showing inside PDF : https://prnt.sc/104sg3v

expected result is "Hello Test hii" instead of "certificate_custom_message"

How do I fix this ?